Extracting the least significant bit in a very large TIFF/JPEG image using open source library
I want to extract the least significant bit (LSB) of each pixel in a very big image (19,566x14,321) that is in TIFF format.
An example of such an image is here: Carina Nebula
This is in JPG format, but the NASA site has the TIFF.
Is there an easy way to do this in C/C++ ImageMagick or open source library?
Many thanks for any suggestions and help!

This question is off-topic on SO "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it." Also question language tagged should contain question related to those languages. Removed

How many bits are in each sample in your source image? And how many samples per pixel? And what do you plan to do with the LSBs once you extract them? libvips is likely to be fast and efficient for this.

@MarkSetchell thank you for this. The RGB is from 0 to 255 in each channel. So, 8 bits per channel. My plan is to test for independence of the LSB in a large image.

@0___________ thank you for your comment. I am not sure why this is off-topic. I think it might be useful for all of us to know if there is an easy tool to do this in the open source library. I do see some questions here using matlab of a similar problem but not of a very large image as my example.

@user3236841 SO rules.

@0___________ yes, I get the rules, but it is not clear if these rules apply here. But let us see if someone has a more helpful answer. Many thanks again!

I can't see why you would want to do it or for that matter how you would define the "LSB of each pixel" in a false colour image that is actually a  set of narrowband images mapped onto RGB 8 bit colour pixels. You basically have to logically or each of the pixel channels with 1 which various image processing packages will allow you to do in their image arithmetic functions. I don't think NASA ever embed steganography into their images (although their workflow does sometimes add multiple thumbnails to the headers).

Agreed that NASA do not embed their images with steganography. The question is if the LSBs in an image are independent or if there is some spatial interaction between them. That is what I am investigating. The NASA image is a large image example.

Not sure what speed you expect but it could be as simple as this with Pillow:
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
Image.MAX_IMAGE_PIXELS = 933120000

# Load image as PIL Image and make into Numpy array
im = Image.open('eta.jpg')
na = np.array(im)

# Mask LSBs and ensure small storage allocation of np.uint8
LSBs = (na & 1).astype(np.uint8)

LSBs.tofile('filename.bin')


Note that you could compress the data before writing. Here's the code for gzip but you can change the word gzip to lzma or bz2 to try other methods:
# Generate some random data
LSBs = np.random.randint(2, size=(20_000, 14_000, 3), dtype=np.uint8).tobytes()

import gzip
compressed = gzip.compress(LSBs)

from pathlib import Path
Path('compressed.bin').write_bytes(compressed)


If you want to save the LSBs as a PNG, start with my original code and add this to the end:
# Mask LSBs and ensure small storage allocation of np.uint8
LSBs = (na & 1).astype(np.uint8)

# Make LSBs into PIL Image and save
pi = Image.fromarray(LSBs)
pi.save('LSBs.png')

You can also try replacing the final line with:
pi.save('LSBs.png', optimize=True)


You can also use CImg just the same if you prefer C++. See http://cimg.eu/ and https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A2836621+%5Bcimg%5D

Thank you, I was wanting something that would take the TIFF/JPEG and give me a binary file of the LSB.

You can write to a binary file with LSBs.tofile('filename.bin')

Using the code above, I get: PIL.Image.DecompressionBombError: Image size (423414686 pixels) exceeds limit of 178956970 pixels, could be decompression bomb DOS attack. Where is this limit set?

OK, I was able to fix this by setting the Image  MAX_IMAGE_PIXELS limit. However, the binary file is 1.2GB in size. What would be a more compressed format to store in?

It shouldn't be quite that big! 20k x 14k by 3 bytes ~ 840MB. I'm guessing you have padded it out to 4 bytes per pixel. But if you are only storing the least significant bit then a two colour bitmap would be the method of choice (one for each channel).

@MartinBrown Oops that was my fault. I tested my code on my iPad and didn't copy the correct line across. I should have added astype(np.uint8) which I will do now.

@MartinBrown Not sure about storing as a PNG - I think half the original problem is that OP is inexperienced in handling images so a PNG, while probably very efficient, isn't going to help.

@MarkSetchell I would be fine with storing each channel as a PNG, how do I do this as a two-colour bitmap?

@MartinBrown can you let me know how I should be able to store each LSB as a two-colour bitmap?

@MarkSetchell I still get a file that is 1.2GB big! However, doing this etire operation is R and storing the LSB as a  3D arrray of TRUE and FALSE  gives me an object of around 269 MB

np.uint8 takes 255 values: is it not possible to get something stored that is a bit?

@user3236841 it is one of the more obscure old legacy formats of MS bitmap image with 1 bit per pixel and two colours in the lookup table. Basically you take 8 original bytes containing 0 or 1 and add them together with suitable shifts into a uint8. Documented on WIki under pixel array you would obviously need to add a header and not all apps can read these ancient formats. Remember to pad each line to a multiple of 4 bytes.
